# C# HttpWebRequest POST strange response

Tags: c#, post, request, httpwebrequest

Good morning, I am writing a program that makes a POST webrequest to a website (websta.me). The request works, but the problem is the response.
I analyzed the http requests using Charles and this is the normal response:

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":{"created_time":"xs","text":"xxxx &lt;3","from":{"username":"xxxx","profile_picture":"xxxx","id":"xxxx","full_name":"xxxx"},"id":"xxxx"},"status":"OK","called_count":x}
```

My program is returning this:

[image: But my program is returning this]

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks in advance for any help :)
This is my code if it can help:

```
byte[] bytes = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("comment=+xxx&media_id=xxx");
HttpWebRequest postReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://websta.me/api/comments/xxx);
WebHeaderCollection postHeaders = postReq.Headers;
postReq.Method = "POST";
postReq.Timeout = 10000;
postReq.Host = "websta.me";
postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0";
postReq.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
postHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
postHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
postHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
postReq.Referer = "http://websta.me/feed";
postReq.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

postReq.CookieContainer = cookies;

postReq.KeepAlive = true;

postHeaders.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
postHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
Stream postStream = postReq.GetRequestStream();
postStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
postStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse postResponse;
postResponse = (HttpWebResponse)postReq.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(postResponse.GetResponseStream());
MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you are receiving from your request is GZip compressed data (the first three bytes are `0x1f8b08`).

To get the text from it, just decompress it using `GZipStream`.  Something like this:

```
private byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
{
    using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(data), CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        const int size = 4096;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
            }
            while (count > 0);
            return memory.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Then modify the end of your code (from where you get your response) to:

```
postResponse = (HttpWebResponse)postReq.GetResponse();
Stream Reader = postResponse.GetResponseStream();
byte[] Data = new byte[postResponse.ContentLength];
Reader.Read(Data, 0, Data.Length);
Data = Decompress(Data);
string Result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Data);
MessageBox.Show(Result);
```

This reads the response data (which is compressed) into a byte array, then decompresses it before converting it to the appropriate text (which I believe is utf-8 from the content-type description).

Please note that the GZip decompression routine is taken from http://www.dotnetperls.com/decompress (it is not mine).